# python list_comprehension to get multiple values

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to do something like below. I want the output of the condition expression in a list comprehension. Is it possible with list comprehension?

```
def why_bad(myvalue): #returns a list of reasons or an empty list it is good
   ...
   return [ reason1, reason2 ..]

bad_values = [ (myvalue,reasons) for myvalue in all_values if (reasons = why_bad(myvalue)) ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
bad_values = [value_tuple for value_tuple in 
                  [(myvalue, why_bad(myvalue)) for myvalue in all_values]
              if value_tuple[1]] # value_tuple[1] == why_bad(myvalue)
```

Or use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
bad_values = filter(lambda value_tuple: value_tuple[1],
                    [(myvalue, why_bad(myvalue)) for myvalue in all_values])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your list comprehension like this, which returns the value and its reasons (or an empty list) for why it is bad:

```
def why_bad(value):
    reasons = []
    if value % 2:
        reasons.append('not divisible by two')
    return reasons

all_values = [1,2,3]

bad_values = [(i, why_bad(i)) for i in all_values]
print bad_values
```

To extend the example, you can add elifs for every different conditional check for why a value is bad and add it to the list.

RETURNS:

```
[(1, ['not divisible by two']), (2, []), (3, ['not divisible by two'])]
```

If all_values has only unique values, though, you might consider creating a dictionary rather than a list comprehension:

```
>>> bad_values = dict([(i, why_bad(i)) for i in all_values])
>>> print bad_values
{1: ['not divisible by two'], 2: [], 3: ['not divisible by two']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but you can try nesting list comprehensions:

```
bad_values = [(v, reasons) for v in all_values 
                           for reasons in [why_bad(v)] if reasons]
```